# Sorting a linked list from lowest value to highest when inserting a new element

Tags: java, list, sorting

I've just created a linked list from scratch where I so far have created two methods for inserting a new element to the list. One method places the element in the beginning og the list and the other places it in the back of the list. I am now trying to create a third method where the element I'm trying to put in the list will be placed depending on the value of the element. So if the element I'm trying to insert is smaller in value than the first element in the list, but lower than the second element in the list, I want the method to automatically place the new element between these two.

It sounds simple in theory, but I now realize it's a lot harder to execute than I could have ever imagined. I can't seem to stop getting NullPointerExceptions and other errors, so at this point I'm completely blank and have no idea what to do next.

Anywas, here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class OrdnetLenkeliste<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Lenkeliste<T>{

    public void insert(T element){
        Node node = new Node(element);
        if(super.isEmpty()){
            node.next = head;
            head = node;
            numberOfNodes++;
        } else {
            Node currentNode = head;
            Node previous = null;

            while(currentNode != null){
                if(currentNode.data.compareTo(node.data) < 0){
                    currentNode = currentNode.next;
                } else if (currentNode.data.compareTo(node.data) > 0 && currentNode.previous.data.compareTo(node.data) < 0){
                    node = currentNode.previous;
                    currentNode.previous = node.previous;
                    currentNode = currentNode.next;
                    numberOfNodes++;
                } else if(currrentNode.data.compareTo(node.data) == 0){
                    currentNode = currentNode.next;
                    currentNode.previous = node;
                    numberOfNodes++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There might be a few spelling errors in the variables, but this is just because I've translated the variable names to make the code more readable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - please always add the *complete* error message(s) and point out which lines in your code sample correspond to the line numbers from this error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your code, and you've made it more complicated than it needs to be.

First, there really are only two cases: either the new node is less than the current node, in which case the new node is inserted before the current node, or it's greater than or equal to the current node and therefore needs to be inserted somewhere further on in the list.

So the idea is really simple:

```
loop until the new node's value is less than the current node's value
insert the new node before the current node
```

The only special cases are when the list is empty or the new node is smaller than the first node. In both cases, the new node becomes the head of the list.

The implementation is more verbose, but not really that complicated.

```
public void insert(T element) 
{
    Node node = new Node(element);
    Node currentNode = head;
    Node previous = null;

    // loop to find the insertion point.
    while (currentNode != null && node.Data.compareTo(currentNode.data) >= 0)
    {
        previous = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }        

    // Insert the item between the previous node and the current node.

    // This node's next pointer references the current node.
    node.next = currentNode;

    if (previous == null)
    {
        // Either the list is empty,
        // or the new node is smaller than the head.
        // This node becomes the head.
        head = node;
    }
    else
    {
        // otherwise, the previous node's next pointer
        // references the current node.
        previous.next = node;
    }
    ++numberOfNodes;
}
```

Comment: That's perfect! Didn't realize it could be so simple

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some mistakes inserting the new element in the linked list.

```
            while(currentNode != null){
                if(currentNode.data.compareTo(node.data) < 0){
                    currentNode = currentNode.next;
                } 
                else if (currentNode.data.compareTo(node.data) > 0 && currentNode.previous == null){
                    currentNode.previous = node;
                    head = node;     
                }
                else if (currentNode.data.compareTo(node.data) > 0 && currentNode.previous.data.compareTo(node.data) < 0){
                    currentNode.previous.next = node; // set the next for previous node of current node
                    node.previous = currentNode.previous; // set previous and next of node
                    node.next = currentNode;
                    currentNode.previous = node; // set the previous of current node
                    numberOfNodes++;
                } else if(currrentNode.data.compareTo(node.data) == 0){
                    // I am not sure what you want to do here, if you want to insert the node before current node, then do the same as above
                    currentNode.previous.next = node; // set the next for previous node of current node
                    node.previous = currentNode.previous; // set previous and next of node
                    node.next = currentNode;
                    currentNode.previous = node; // set the previous of current node
                    numberOfNodes++;
                }
            }
```